# How to set default ruby version using rvm

Tags: ruby, macos

I've set my default ruby version with

```
rvm use 1.9.3 --default
```

When opening a new terminal I can see that rvm remembers my default, however the old version of ruby is used:

```
Last login: Tue Jan 22 17:36:20 on ttys000
➜  ~  rvm list default

Default Ruby (for new shells)

   ruby-1.9.3-p374 [ x86_64 ]

➜  ~  ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]

➜  ~  rvm info

ruby-1.9.3-p374:

  system:
    uname:       "Darwin murzemac.local 12.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 12.2.0: Sat Aug 25 00:48:52 PDT 2012; root:xnu-2050.18.24~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64"
    system:      "osx/10.8/x86_64"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin12)"
    zsh:         "/bin/zsh => zsh 4.3.11 (i386-apple-darwin12.0)"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.17.10 () by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]"
    updated:      "14 hours 46 minutes 38 seconds ago"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "1.8.7"
    date:         "2012-02-08"
    platform:     "universal-darwin12.0"
    patchlevel:   "2012-02-08 patchlevel 358"
    full_version: "ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/Users/murze/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374"
    ruby:         "/Users/murze/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/usr/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/usr/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/usr/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/usr/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Users/murze/.rvm/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     "/Users/murze/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374"
    GEM_PATH:     "/Users/murze/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374:/Users/murze/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/Users/murze/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374"
    IRBRC:        "/Users/murze/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""
```

How can 1.9.3 be automatically activated when opening a new terminal window?

Comment: https://rvm.io/workflow/rvmrc/ may be of use

Comment: Append the output of `rvm info` to your question please. That will help us diagnose the problem.

Comment: Maybe 1.8.7 is installed *outside* of rvm (by default on a Mac?) and is getting loaded after the rvm version. See this answer re. checking path order:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/14530553/550712.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My default doesn't always correctly set either, so I've put a .rvmrc in the directory my terminal opens at (or in dirs my terminal is likely to open at) with `rvm use default` inside.

Comment: this considerably slows down my terminal at start.