# Installed Ruby 1.9.3 but ruby -v keeps showing 1.8.7 every new terminal

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

Eventhough I have Ruby 1.9.3 installed via RVM, every time I open a new Terminal and run "ruby -v" I get:

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin11.0]
```

"rvm list" shows:

```
rvm rubies

   ruby-1.9.3-p362 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-1.9.3-p374 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

I've tried entering "rvm use 1.9.3 --default" but it only works for the current terminal session.  Opening new terminals always reverts back to 1.8.7.

I've also made sure that my ~/.bash_profile contains at the end:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

What can I do so that I don't have to type "rvm use 1.9.3" every time I open a terminal?

Comment: @Veger: 1.8.7 is system, so that would be pretty hard

Comment: Are you sure that the .bash_profile is being loaded? IIRC, there are some profiles that can override .bash_profile

Comment: @JimDeville It is hard-coded in OS X?! I thought they (started to) use packages as well? Ah well, that is another non-related question... :)

Comment: @Veger: IIRC, it is hard coded, and you probably don't want to remove it because there are probably a few places that expect it :|

Comment: @JimDeville: Yes, I added an echo statement to the .bash_profile to see if it was being loaded and it definitely is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your `.rvm` directory is in your `PATH`

Comment: rvm directory is in the PATH.

Comment: Make sure it's at the beginning of your PATH.

Comment: @nbarraille: That did it!  Can't believe it was something so silly.

Comment: I found it necessary to also include $rvm_bin_path to begginning of path